# How to get source HTML from gecko web browser? InnerHtml does not exist any more

Tags: c#, gecko, geckofx

[GeckoFx](http://bitbucket.org/geckofx/geckofx-22.0) v22

```
GeckoElement element = null;
var geckoDomElement = WebBrowser1.Document.DocumentElement;
if(geckoDomElement  is GeckoElement)
  element = (GeckoElement)geckoDomElement ;

var innerHtml = element.InnerHtml;
```

but there is no more `InnerHtml` method. How to get source HTML from gecko web browser?

Comment: Is there any documentation?

Comment: Are you sure it's not `element.InnerHTML`? I know some browsers are case sensitive so this may be also?

Comment: No there is nothing with Inner*

Comment: `GeckoElement` doesn't have an `InnerHtml` property, but `GeckoHtmlElement` does.

Comment: and how can i get GeckoHtmlElement?

Comment: have you tried `geckoWebBrowser1.ViewSource()` ???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cast to GeckoHtmlElement instead of a GeckoElement.

```
GeckoHtmlElement element = null;
var geckoDomElement = WebBrowser1.Document.DocumentElement;
if(geckoDomElement is GeckoHtmlElement)
{
  element = (GeckoHtmlElement)geckoDomElement;    
  var innerHtml = element.InnerHtml;
}
```