# C# - GeckoFX vs InnerHTML

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, geckofx

If I would use default Visualstudio webBrowser control (IE) i would just write something like this:

```
textBox3.Text = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("mydivid").InnerHtml;
```

But I'm stubborn to use GeckoFX (Mozilla) and ofcourse it doesn't work. What I found is information that I need to adress "HTMLDocument" not "Document" to pull my desired value. But no example that fit my needs.
How to get this innerHTML of this particular element?

--- Response to @Timothy Groote ---

I've read the other topic - there's no example of code with `GetElementById`, it's like wide definition, but I need specific one - I cannot read this codeand get clear information what method or property shoueld I use in my app.

I can add that my element is and will be always HTML element, so i don't need to verify that every time with "if".

When I use "the other code" in my app result (instead of innerHTML) was only:

```
<head></head><body></body>
```

In "the other code" has also a mistake:

```
var geckoDomElement = WebBrowser1.Document.DocumentElement;
```

**There's no webBrowser1 control!** Only geckoWebBrowser1, neither works!

--- Edit2 ---

I was also thinking about something like that:

```
textBox3.text = (GeckoHtmlElement)geckoWebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("mydivid")....
```

but there's also no "innerHtml"

in

```
(GeckoHtmlElement)geckoWebBrowser1.Document.DocumentElement
```

there's no "getElementById".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get source HTML from gecko web browser? InnerHtml does not exist any more](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20547402/how-to-get-source-html-from-gecko-web-browser-innerhtml-does-not-exist-any-more)

Comment: you are better off using http://www.awesomium.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ANSWER
Of course defining variable:

```
GeckoHtmlElement machcode;
```

Finding element:

```
machcode = geckoWebBrowser1.Document.GetHtmlElementById("machinecode");
```

And finally reading the content:

```
textBox3.Text = machcode.InnerHtml;
```

And one important thing was to place code in DocumentComplete event!

Every solutions provided in web were wrong - some point into nonexisting webBrowser1 control, some forget about definition, some throw null exception, some use wrong GetElement instead of GetHtmlElement.

Answer (score 2):

If you using Geckofx 45 then its very simple , just try like this....

`GeckoHtmlElement testelement = null;
 testelement = (GeckoHtmlElement)webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("test");
 string text=testelement .InnerHtml;`

if you don't know how to use Geckofx 45 then try this simple tutorial .. 
[How to use or embed Geckofx 45 Webbrowser control into Visual Studio into WinForms Applications](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o8f8Iv1f040)

Comment: Don't have webBrowser1 in my app (as i wrote before) = this code do not work.

To make thing simpler i want to put readed innerHTML value straight into textbox3, without any variable.

`textBox3.Text = (GeckoHtmlElement)webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("test").InnerHtml;`


Why I need to define null element?

Comment: Also - linked tutorial is only about including Gecko package into project, as I did in the very beggining.

Comment: you can not use innerHtml before converting an element into htmlElement. You will get innerHtml only after convert element to htmlElement. innerhtml only htmlElement property.

Comment: Alright I understand, but still no answer how to do that.

Comment: any new solution maybe?